# any free SQL Server 2005 express database schema generation and reverse engineering tool?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

thanks for your time and sharing.

Please guide me is there some free tool (to use with SQL Server 2005 Express edition) that can generate data base schema by making diagrame and reverse engineering of an existing database ?

Thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

[Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express.aspx)

[Download it here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796)

Comment: Thanks for replying marc_S, as I mentioned I am already using SQL Server Express 2005. But if I am not mistaken it do not provide reverse engineering and creating schema from diagrams. please guide

Comment: @Haansi: the default SQL Server 2005 Express does **NOT** include the Management Studio Express - that's a graphical tool to query your database, and to create database diagrams and stuff like that....